Imposition of order parameter constraint into free energy functional
I consider free energy functional at transition point
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{F} = \int d^4 r \big[\frac{b}2 (\nabla \phi)^2 + \frac{\lambda}{24} (\phi^2)^2 \big],
\end{equation}
where $\phi$ is 4 component order parameter
\begin{equation}
\phi^2 = \sum_{i=1}^4 \phi^2_i \qquad (\nabla \phi)^2 = \sum_{i=1}^4 (\nabla\phi_i)^2
\end{equation}
I want to examine RG equations of coefficents $b,\lambda$ when external constraint is added: $\sum_i \nabla_i \phi_i =0$
I tried to take this constraint into account directly, by expressing one of the components of order parameters through the others. I obtained complicated answer for effective functional for slow modes. It is seems irrational for me, because it lost original symmetry of $\mathcal{F}$.
I wonder if there is a method to take into acoount constraints in free energy functional systematically.
